# Close flow screen after the Flow finishes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, visual-workflow, lightning-components

Calling a flow from Quick Action wasnt refreshing the screen , so I calling the Update Screen action from the https://unofficialsf.com/the-update-screen-flow-action-component/.  Quick Action updates the owner of the case record to be the current through the flow. After the case is updated I see the screen like

[image]

Instead of showing the screen at the end of flow finishes, is there a way we can automatically close it through the Update Screen lightning component. I will save the user the key clicks every time they try to update something. I tried to add `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();` which would do complete refresh but I still see that screen
Component of the Update Screen

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowActions,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"
                    description="An error message bound to force:recordData"/>
    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                      />
    </aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    invoke : function(component, event, helper) {        
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {           
component.find("recordLoader").reloadRecord(true, $A.getCallback(function() {
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
                resolve();
            }));
        });
    }})
```

Can anyone suggest me any options for closing flow screen automatically through the lightning component here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have available [Flow Navigation Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_screens_navigate_actions.htm) to you in the aura component.

[image]

You need to use [these](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_screens_navigate_custom.htm) to control the flow execution. It seems the unofficialSF component is a flow action. You can simply add another flow screen that uses an aura component that will essentially auto-finish for you and implements `lightning:availableForFlowScreens`.

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
</aura:component>
```

```
({
   doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
      var navigate = component.get("v.navigateFlow");
      navigate("FINISH");
   }
})
```

Comment: Yea I understand adding the finish button would resolve. It will again be an extra click for the user to close the screen right, I am checking with out an extra screen/ click if there is a way to close the screen from lightning component

Comment: It doesn't have to be a click, you can call the navigate whenever you'd like so it doesn't need user intervention. My example uses an example of a button as that's the typical use case, but you can navigate whenever you'd like as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you, Can you please give an example of how to navigate from the Update Screen lightning component

Comment: I'm not familiar with that unofficialSF component. I edited where I think it would work but cannot confirm/test myself

Comment: Thank you for your effort.. Yeah it is failing `Error in $A.getCallback() [navigate is not a function]`

Comment: ah, you need to include `lightning:availableForFlowScreens` in implements on the component. Since this is an action, it might make more sense to add a screen that has an aura component that does this finish action immediately on initialization.